# Oracle SQL Query running fifty times

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm having trouble with a query. I'm trying to return a single value from a db query using a subquery(in the end I need to have multiple subqueries that return a single value. I keep getting 50 rows returning that each have the same value though.

If I run the subquery alone it returns just a single value, but when I use it as a subquery it returns many rows. This is with Oracle SQL can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(avg(elapsedtime),0) 
    FROM TableName WHERE functioncallid = 'functionName'))   
    "newname" FROM TableName
```

Comment: you're not getting anything from the subquery.

Comment: Hi Alfabravo, I'm not sure what you mean. I do receive the average elapsed time, and if I include multiple subqueries with different predicates I get a column for each with a different value in each, but that row is repeated 50+ times in the output.

Comment: Check @Dave Costa's answer. That's the point about your subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, your query has the basic format:

```
SELECT (scalar-subquery) FROM TableName
```

You are selecting all rows from `TableName`, and for each you are returning the value of the subquery.  I assume that the table has 50 rows, and this is why you are seeing the value 50 times.  This is no different than `SELECT 1 FROM TableName`.

A quick fix would be to use DUAL as your row source in the outer query:

```
SELECT (scalar-subquery) FROM DUAL
```

DUAL is a one-row, one-column table.  This will cause your subquery result to be returned one time.  If you then want additional subqueries as other columns, you can do that easily:

```
SELECT (scalar-subquery), (other-scalar-subquery) FROM DUAL
```

You might be going about this the wrong way.  If the predicate in the various subqueries will be the same, you shouldn't need the nested queries at all:

```
SELECT COALESCE(avg(elapsedtime),0) , COALESCE(max(elapsedtime),0)
FROM TableName WHERE functioncallid = 'functionName'
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much for the answer. Each of the predicates is different, but your suggestion to use DUAL works perfectly.